# How to do cross server matchmaking in roblox?

Tags: sql, lua, roblox

I am trying to have matchmaking across servers for a game I am making where players would get matched up by how many points they have. I don't know how to do this though. I know maybe something with data stores or sql but I don't know where to start. If anyone could give me some pointers, or a general outline on how to do this it would help out a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No need for an external site hosting a SQL server, it would only add unnecessary external dependencies. Roblox [datastores](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=Data_store) are the way to go.

With a simple [google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=roblox%20matchmaking) you should find relevant data. And with a simple [search on the roblox wiki](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?search=Matchmaking) you can find the [official guide for matchmaking](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=Matchmaking).

The guide offers all necessary information and even uncopylocked example places: [Lobby](http://www.roblox.com/Matchmaking-Lobby-place?id=181194460) and [Arena](http://www.roblox.com/Matchmaking-Arena-place?id=181238621)

---

As the datastore is shared between all [Places](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=Place) (thus servers) in a [Game](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=Game), you can store the matching data there.

For example: you have a list with all players available to matching, and let the server match between them when a new player is added.

The proccess is similar to the above mentioned guide, you just have to share the matching-data between the servers with the datastore instead of just using it to transfer data.

A problem to keep in mind is [race conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) although the [Update function](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=Data_store#UpdateAsync) have some functionality to make it easier to avoid.

Comment: Yeah but thats only for matchmaking on one server I wanted to do it across multiple servers.

Comment: @JoeMckinstry Added some more info. If possible you should add more info about your case, else it might be "too broad". What do you mean with "between servers"? Do you mean server instances or places? Why do you need many servers and not a lobby?